Extract dates in an text
I have a text with Shamsi date like this:

Pathology report on 01.09.1402 (22.11.2023): Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin.
Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.

I want to extract all the dates in an array.
How would you do that?
So far we have this:


const text = `Pathology report on 01.09.1402: Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin. Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.`

console.log(getDate(text));

function getDate(d) {
  var day, month, year;

  result = d.match("[0-9]{2}([\-/ \.])[0-9]{2}[\-/ \.][0-9]{4}");
  if (null != result) {
    dateSplitted = result[0].split(result[1]);
    day = dateSplitted[0];
    month = dateSplitted[1];
    year = dateSplitted[2];
  }
  result = d.match("[0-9]{4}([\-/ \.])[0-9]{2}[\-/ \.][0-9]{2}");
  if (null != result) {
    dateSplitted = result[0].split(result[1]);
    day = dateSplitted[2];
    month = dateSplitted[1];
    year = dateSplitted[0];
  }

  if (month > 12) {
    aux = day;
    day = month;
    month = aux;
  }

  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
  
  
}




So when you want to extract information from a text, and it follows a certain pattern using regex expression, makes sense.
So what I have done is create an array called dates so I can use it to store the information you want which is the date.
Then I look at the regex docs to create a regex_pattern which matches your text, I called it regex not a good name you might need to change it
the regex.exec(interesting_date) is used to find each date match within the string you provided. Then we just simply return dates:
I have provided a code snippet which also takes care of date and month
const text = `Pathology report on 01.09.1402 (22.11.2023): Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin. Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.`;

console.log(getDates(text));

function getDates(interesting_date) {
  const dates = [];
  const regex = /\b\d{2}[-/ .]\d{2}[-/ .]\d{4}\b/g; // Regex to match all date formats

  let match;
  while ((match = regex.exec(interesting_date)) !== null) {
    dates.push(match[0]); // Add each matched date to the array
  }

  return dates;
}

The final result is this:
[ '01.09.1402', '22.11.2023', '30.03.1403' ]


1402 and 1403 looks like Shamsi years
Then you need to loop to get all of them


function getAllDates(d) {
  let dates = [];
  const regex = /[0-9]{2}([-/ .])[0-9]{2}\1[0-9]{4}/g;
  let match;

  while ((match = regex.exec(d)) !== null) {
    let dateSplitted = match[0].split(match[1]);
    let day = dateSplitted[0];
    let month = dateSplitted[1];
    let year = dateSplitted[2];

    // Swap day and month if necessary
    if (parseInt(month) > 12) {
      let aux = day;
      day = month;
      month = aux;
    }

    dates.push(`${day}.${month}.${year}`);
  }

  return dates;
}

const text = `Pathology report on 01.09.1402: Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin. Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.`;

console.log(getAllDates(text));




The easiest way to achieve this would be calling String.prototype.match with a global (g) match on the following pattern: \d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}.
I separated the extraction from the formatting so that they are not coupled.


const text = "Pathology report on 01.09.1402 (22.11.2023): Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin. Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.";

const extractDates = (textStr) =>
  textStr.match(/\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}/g).map(dateStr =>
    (([date, month, year]) => new Date(year, month - 1, date))
    (dateStr.split(/\./g)));

// Close to date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE') with explicit padding
const formatDate = (dateObj) => {
  const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  const month = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
  const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
  return `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
}

const extractedDates = extractDates(text).map(formatDate);

console.log(extractedDates);




In the old code, only one date format was handled, and it only returned the first matching date. Additionally, if the month was greater than 12, the day and month were swapped, which caused issues with Shamsi dates. The new code, however, extracts all dates from the text and returns them in the DD.MM.YYYY format. It supports both Shamsi and Gregorian date formats, ensuring that dates are correctly formatted and adjusts day and month values when necessary, providing a more comprehensive and accurate date extraction.
You can try this :

function extractDates(text) {
  const regex = /(\d{2}[./-]\d{2}[./-]\d{4})/g;
  const matches = text.match(regex);
  
  if (!matches) return [];

  const formattedDates = matches.map(date => {
    let [day, month, year] = date.split(/\.|-|\//);

    if (parseInt(month) > 12) {
      [day, month] = [month, day];
    }

    return `${day.padStart(2, '0')}.${month.padStart(2, '0')}.${year}`;
  });

  return formattedDates;
}

const text = "Pathology report on 01.09.1402 (22.11.2023): Baso-squamous carcinoma in right thigh skin. Surgical pathology report on 30.03.1403, Multiple lymphoid tissue involved by metastatic epithelial tumor of right inguinal mass.";

console.log(extractDates(text));

